# How does one "navigate" by train across Central Europe?

Tags: vienna, prague, budapest, salzburg, lucerne

We are a family of 4, 2 youth aged 21 and 24. We plan to reach Lucerne on 19th of July 2014.... Lucerne-2 nights, then Salzburg 3 Night, then Vienna 3 nights, then Budapest 3 nights and Prague 3 nights and fly out. That is, we will visit four different countries, Switzerland, Austria, Hungary, the Czech Republic, overland.

1. Are there better ways to travel in some countries and different ways for others? For instance, the eurail pass in some countries or buy sector tickets in others?
2. Should these tickets be bought at the venue in some countries? Or online for others?

Comment: This question is about constructing/evaluating itineraries and budgeting. Hence, IMO it will be considered off-topic on this website.

Comment: I "streamlined" the question by asking if there are "better ways" to travel/buy tickets in some countries than others, and wonder if the question can be re-opened in its current form. The itinerary is a "given" but the "travel means" is now the focus of the question.

Comment: @TomAu I think now it would require to be posted as multiple separate questions rather than one single question asking about EuRail passes and trains vs flights vs road etc. about 4 countries.

Comment: @AdityaSomani: OK, "closer" but not yet there.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I have no information on the particular area. But for train travel in general you may find this page really helpful: http://seat61.com/

It gives detailes info on your railpass question: http://seat61.com/Railpass-and-Eurail-pass-guide.htm You maybe have to find out yourself what the right choice is.